# Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS 4.3 SDK installation problem on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, development, ios, xcode

I recently brought a new Mac mini running Max OS X 10.7 Lion.

I downloaded the iOS SDK 4.3 and Xcode 3.2.6.dmg from Apple.

The download was successful and I was able to install it without any problem. But after installing, I cannot find Xcode in the `/Developer/Applications` folder.

All I do see there are performance tools and utilities folders.

Can anybody help me in properly installing Xcode on Lion?

Answer (score 2):

For Lion you need Xcode 4 (not 3.2) This is available from the App Store or from a paid Developer account).

This will install the installer in /Applications, run this to install Xcode to /Developer

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark.Do i need to remove Xcode 3.2 before installing xcode 4?The standard uninstall command for uninstalling xcode is also not working.Can i directly install xcode 4?

Comment: xcode 3 and 4 can coexist - so if you have xcode 3 just add xcode 4 - in SL xcode 3 is renamed to /Developer-old

Answer (score 0):

Look again in Applications. There's an `Install Xcode` application.

Run it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Randolph.I checked in /DEVELOPER/APPLICATIONS folder. There is nothing like that.And also in /DEVELOPER/Library folder there is no uninstall.So i am unable to uninstall it.

Comment: It's in _/Applications_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno- It is not present in /Applications

Comment: The "Install Xcode" app is only present if you're downloading Xcode from the App Store. And if he were doing that, it would be Xcode 4, not Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: @Sreeram I was referring to Xcode 4.1, which is the version you should install on Mac OS X Lion.